# Working with jYearChooser and jMonthChooser

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jdatechooser

i'm working in java swing and i need to get year a jYearChooser and month from a jMonthChooser and then format it to this format "*yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00*"
Here is my code , but it doesn't give the expected output

```
int year = jYearChooser1.getYear();
int month = jMonthChooser1.getMonth();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
Date dt = new Date(year, month,00);
Date todate = dateFormat.format(dt);
```

please help me

Comment: What exactly do you expect and what is the output?

Comment: I choose 2016 as the year and March as the month but the output is 3916-03-29 00:00:00 @AlexanderBaltasar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because **year** parameter is specific in Date class constructor:

```
**
 * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it so that
 * it represents midnight, local time, at the beginning of the day
 * specified by the <code>year</code>, <code>month</code>, and
 * <code>date</code> arguments.
 *
 * @param   year    the year minus 1900.
 * @param   month   the month between 0-11.
 * @param   date    the day of the month between 1-31.
 * @see     java.util.Calendar
 * @deprecated As of JDK version 1.1,
 * replaced by <code>Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date)</code>
 * or <code>GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date)</code>.
 */
@Deprecated
public Date(int year, int month, int date) {
    this(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Also you can notice that this constructor is [@Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html). So better idea is to use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, 1); // Specify day of month

String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```